Character movement problems
I have been working with Blender for almost a year and all the characters that have been using this design software until now have the same problem. I am new to this field. Is there anyone who has encountered this problem? and has solved it


All my characters are deformed when posing or moving, as you can see in the picture.

Hello, maybe smmoth the vertex groups? But apart from that, do you really need to use so many polygons for your character? Why not less poly with a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Yes, I can smooth it with the sculpt brush, and I want the clan to not have such a problem because I want to move it, about the number of polygons, because I wanted it to look like realistic details, I increased the number of polygons.
